# Where are the user bookmark settings stored for Nemo in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

I am currently using Linux Mint 18.2, Cinnamon 3.4.6, and Nemo 3.4.6 aswell.

I seem to be having an issue with `Nemo`. My places (those bookmarks that are like Music, Pictures, Documents, etc) are now in my bookmarks section and without icons. All they show is a folder icon and the symbolic link icon next to them (since I have my Music, Pictures, Documents and such all located on an external hdd). This is making it difficult to determine which is which since I usually determine the folder by what icon it has first. It doesn't help that the places bookmarks are not in their original positions. This has happened twice already. I can't remember exactly how I was able to fix the issue before, but I remember there was a bookmarks `config` file with bookmarks and places separated. I don't remember where it is located but it fixed the problem.

So, that is what I am asking. Where the bookmarks `config` file for `nemo` is. I am sure it will fix this same issue for a second time. If anybody has any alternative way to fix this issue, I am all ears. Maybe possibly resetting all the settings of `nemo`? I don't know.

Comment: Can you use the menu option Bookmarks -> Edit Bookmarks to fix this?

Comment: No, as it doesn't appear to have an option. Unless there is something I don't know about. All the folders are named correctly, and just show up as regular bookmarks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bookmarks are loaded from `/home/<username>/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. (Using `strace` to see what files are accessed. Also adding bookmark adds to this file, and adding lines to this file adds bookmarks.) This file looks like this:

```
file:///home/<username>/Documents Documents
file:///home/<username>/Music Music
file:///home/<username>/Pictures Pictures
file:///home/<username>/Videos Videos
file:///home/<username>/Downloads Downloads
```

Images used are located in `/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/places/16`. (Path will vary depending on your theme.)

Answer (score 3):

While bookmarks are configured at `/home/<username>/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`, as @user224348 pointed out, Places (which are a special type of bookmark with icons according to certain categories: documents, templates etc.) are configured at `/home/<username>/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, or via the `xdg-user-dirs-update` command.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem myself. 
I've solved that with Links.
To make it work follow those steps:

1. Move any data in the original folders to the desired new locations.
2. Delete the folders from your Home folder.
3. Select the folders in the desired new location and drag them to the home location while pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. 
   Make sure the folders names are identical to the original names in your home folder.
4. A menu will pop-up asking what action to take. Select "Link Here".
5. Add the bookmarks of the linked folders to the bookmarks pane.

You will see the folders with their original emblems (icons) in your bookmarks pane, and as a side effect, all the system actions will point now to your new locations, so there is no need to change any of the default locations for Downloads, Documents, etc...

Hope that this is useful.